# listener on the edges of the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I have a listener on the edges of the layout. Lets say I one linear layout that has 2 linear layouts inside it. How can I have a listener on the edges of one of the linear layouts inside

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/big">
      <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout1"/>
      <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout2"/>  
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I know when the user touches the top edge of layout2?
Thank you

Comment: you can define a rectangle relative to your relative lay out and on touch listener of your linear layout check the user touch point is inside your defined rectangle or not, just a hint how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a FrameLayout on the outside of it with a padding.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/big">
      <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout1"/>
      <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/layout2_wrapper" android:padding="10dip">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout2"/>  
      </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: And how Can I add the listener to the frameLayout edge so that only when the edge is clicked  I execute a certain code?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Comment: I know how to add a listner in general. But I am saying how can I listen to touches or clicks on "the edge" only.

Comment: Only the edge of the FrameLayout would be visible, if the LinearLayout fills the FrameLayout. So if you add a listener to the FrameLayout it should only listen for a click on the outside edge of the LinearLayout. (the FrameLayout should wrap_content and the LinearLayout fill_parent)