# android listener for click on edge of the screen

Tags: android

i want to implement event listeners for clicks on both side of the screen

do I have to create invisible views/layouts that lie on each side of the screen and have click listener on them?

if so what kind of layout/view should i create and whats the code for positioning them to the side of the screen

i found this post [listener on the edges of the layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579125/listener-on-the-edges-of-the-layout)
but i dont really get it.

Comment: try to make your layout fill_parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add this to the parent layout of the activity (the first layout in the xml file).

```
View touchView = findViewById(R.id.yourParentView);
    touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
                String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
                return true;
        }
    });
```

Then using `X` and `Y`and calculating the device screen size you can check for the edges.
Here is how to calculate the screen size (in pixels)

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Before `getSize` was introduced (in API level 13), you could use the `getWidth` and `getHeight` methods that are now deprecated:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```